Relative path or subdirectory with Laravel 11 vite
In Laravel 11 with vite I am loading a font in my .scss file:
src:url("../fonts/my-font.eot");

Vite build this into this css:
src:url(/build/assets/my-font.eot);

How can I tell vite to create relative URLs like:
src:url(./my-font.eot);

Absolute path would be fine to, if I could add my subdirectory /my-app. root and publicDir option have no effect. Maybe laravel plugin overwrites this?
I searched through the manual and tried a lot of options without success.

Can you elaborate on why you need a path without the app domain?

by default, vite builds without domain using absolute path only! Are you sure you didn't make any default changes to vite config file?

@OMiShah you are right. Absolute path do work but I deploy in a subdirectory: /my-app that does not work out of the box. I rewrote my question.

First run npm update to get a somewhat new version. It does not work for older version like laravel-vite-plugin 0.7.1, vite 3.2.5. But it does with (still old) laravel-vite-plugin 0.7.8, vite 3.2.11.
Now adding  base: './' in the Vite config file should work and the resulting build files should use relative instead of absolute file path.
Vite config file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    // Relative path
    base: './',
    // Absolute path
    // base: '/subfolder/build',
});

But if wish to have absolute path with subdirectroy you can then simply specify base: 'subfolder/build' and resulting build files will have absolute paths (for e.g.): /subfolder/build/assets/filename.css

You are half correct. It does this work way but only with newer versions. I added npm update in your answer. Thanks really helped a lot.
